# Error in your SQL syntax 'WHERE c.name LIKE '%%''

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm looking to produce the below table with search and pagination by joining 4 tables - categories, subcategories, childCategories and products.

[image: output table]

The backend code to acheive the above is:

```
const [rows, fields] = await mysqlConnPool.promise().execute(
      `SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(DISTINCT(s.id)) AS subCategories, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT(ch.id)) AS childCategories, COUNT(p.id) AS products 
      FROM categories c
      LEFT JOIN subCategories s ON c.id = s.categoryId 
      LEFT JOIN childCategories ch ON s.id = ch.subCategoryId 
      LEFT JOIN products p ON ch.id = p.childCategoryId GROUP BY c.id
      ORDER BY c.id ASC LIMIT ${size} OFFSET ${page * size}`
    );
```

However, when I try to implement the search functionality, it throws a Mysql syntax error.
Please help to identify the error and point the correct syntax:

```
const [rows, fields] = await mysqlConnPool.promise().execute(
      `SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(DISTINCT(s.id)) AS subCategories, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT(ch.id)) AS childCategories, COUNT(p.id) AS products 
      FROM categories c
      LEFT JOIN subCategories s ON c.id = s.categoryId 
      LEFT JOIN childCategories ch ON s.id = ch.subCategoryId 
      LEFT JOIN products p ON ch.id = p.childCategoryId GROUP BY c.id
      ORDER BY c.id ASC LIMIT ${size} OFFSET ${page * size}
      WHERE c.name LIKE '%${search}%'`
    );
```

But it throws the following error:
[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the right syntax, posting if helpful to someone else:

```
const [rows, fields] = await mysqlConnPool.promise().execute(
      `SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(DISTINCT(s.id)) AS subCategories, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT(ch.id)) AS childCategories, COUNT(p.id) AS products 
      FROM categories c 
      LEFT JOIN subCategories s ON c.id = s.categoryId 
      LEFT JOIN childCategories ch ON s.id = ch.subCategoryId 
      LEFT JOIN products p ON ch.id = p.childCategoryId
      WHERE c.name LIKE '%${search}%' GROUP BY c.id
      ORDER BY c.id ASC LIMIT ${size} OFFSET ${page * size}`
    );
```

WHERE clause needs to come before GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below updated query.

```
const [rows, fields] = await mysqlConnPool.promise().execute(
      `SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(DISTINCT(s.id)) AS subCategories, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT(ch.id)) AS childCategories, COUNT(p.id) AS products 
      FROM categories c 
      LEFT JOIN subCategories s ON c.id = s.categoryId 
      LEFT JOIN childCategories ch ON s.id = ch.subCategoryId 
      LEFT JOIN products p ON ch.id = p.childCategoryId
      WHERE c.name LIKE '%${search}%' GROUP BY c.id
      ORDER BY c.id ASC LIMIT ${size} OFFSET ${page * size}`
```